# SQL Server flat world map on geometry column

Tags: sql-server, geometry, geography

I need help regarding geometry and geography columns. Well not much about geography as that works fine. What im trying to achieve is to represent world map on geometry column instead of geography. Well not really represent itself but to be able to measure distance between two coordinates on flat map (as i know geography makes curves as earth itself is curved of course). Is there any way to do this?

I was reading a bit but nothing has make any difference to it if i do:

```
DECLARE @g geometry;

SET @g = geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(-122.360 47.656, -122.343 47.656)', 0);

SELECT @g.STLength();
```

I get distance 0.016 while for geography its 1277... changing srid to 4326 doesn't change it also.. any help?

Answer (score 0):

The geometry datatype is for Cartesian geometry. The line that you've defined is from point (x1, y1) = (-122.360, 47.656) to (x2, y2) = (-122.343, 47.656). The distance between these is sqrt( (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 ).

With the geography datatype, the points are given as degrees around the equator and degrees of inclination from the equator. The calculation of distance between two points so defined is given by the Haversine formula.

As you can see, the two are vastly different. But the real question is: what are you really trying to accomplish? If your points represent points on a globe, why are you using the geometry datatype at all?

Comment: Yea I know it's different and generally I'm using geography type. What I'm trying to accomplish its to prove that geometry data is flat. So given two points having same distance from each other result will be different cos geometry won't count curve of the earth. Then again I'd like to have same value as measure so meters in that case. But I don't know if there is easy way to map geography to geometry to keep those points in the same distance